# Autolayout "Safe Area" is missing when adding constraint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I'm new to IOS app development and currently studying Auto Layout.

Sometimes, "Safe Area" is missing when I'm adding constraint.

I'm trying to add constraint for my StackView with 0, 0, 0, 0 for leading, trailing, top and bottom relative to "Safe Area", but for some reason "Safe Area" is missing in the constraint option. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at other answers on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your stack view is out of the `safeArea`. You can manually minimize the stack view (with all content) to fit the `safeArea` view and try again.

[image]

Comment: Yup, that did the trick for me. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Control click the stackView and drag the cursor to safe area, then click on:

- Leading space to safe area
- Trailing space to safe area
- Bottom space to safe area
- Top space to safe area

[image: drag to safe area]